# Upvote is not counted until you refresh the page (iOS app)

Tags: bug, ios-app, up-votes

1. iOS app (v1.4.5), Stack Overflow;
2. I've read a good question, so I've upvoted it;
3. My upvote is shown on the Question itself, but when I go to the general questions' stack I don't see that that Question has any upvotes.

Yesterday (when I noticed this for the first time) the refresh of the page updated the upvote count, but today even when I refresh the page, the count remains 0.
[image]